# xamarin forms - web api call synchronous get/post using c# in pcl

Tags: c#, api, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, portable-class-library

I am developing an app in which I have created a user model with user details like name, age etc. I am making an api call with login credentials to my created web api which will return User details. i need to make my call async. But since http client is available only in Xamarin Forms. So I need my code to wait till api returns data. How can I do it??

I thought one way to do this by declaring global variable and then setting it by data returned by web api but I get some some while making my code to wait till it is initialized.

Due to using async one by one every method is getting async!

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://url/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Username", Username),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", Password)
                });
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/webapi/login", content);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                    using (HttpContent requestResponse = response.Content)
                    {
                        string result = await requestResponse.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        if (result != null && result.Length >= 50)
                        {
                            //isconnected = Convert.ToBoolean(result);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //to do something
                }

            }
```

Comment: HttpClient is the concept of C# doesn't mean available in xamarin.forms only. it's better you make two services in your pcl such as to Get data and to Post data. When you need to call Login web api pass the argument to the get data and return the response in the form of object where you perform the desired operation.

Comment: But the methods for get set will be async because GetAsync and PostAsync methods are available in xamarin forms.

Comment: I wanted to say that only httpclient is available in xamarin forms pcl for calling web api.

Comment: There is also HttpWebRequest you can use, but yes absolutely the methods will be async, so better maintain a time out for every web API call.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to say then maybe its an idea to wrap the await method call in a Task.Run()?